# Using jQuery to toggle specific classes [misleading?]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three article tags that each have 1 section which I need to animate to appear i.e height from 0px to whatever px. Each article has an ID what is the most efficient way to have an on click event for each one without writing a separate function for each individual id i.e is there a 'get clicked article's id' type method?

Thanks

Comment: $(this).id? or $(this).get(0).id perhaps.. should be there somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do,

jQuery:

```
$('.art h1').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().find('p').stop(true).slideToggle(); 
});
```

html:

```
<div class="art">
    <h1>Some article stuff</h1>
    <p>text goes here</p>
</div>
```

fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pYRr5/)

If you want it to slide up and have only one open at a time then you can make a minor edit like so,

jQuery:

```
$('.art h1').on('click', function() {    
    $('.art p').slideUp();
    $(this).parent().find('p').stop(true).slideToggle(); 
});
```

fiddle: [Only one active JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pYRr5/1/)

Comment: Got a follow up question how can I have it so that it doesnt register any clicks inside the section of each article, as i have a form inside there which when clicked, is causing the whole thing to collapse again. thanks

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for me to see the structure?

Comment: Don't worry fixed it by looking for the click on a title span tag as opposed to the whole article :) thanks for offering to help though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple selectors with a comma:

```
$('#id1,#id2,#id3').click(function() {
    $(this).animate(...);
});
```

...or you could add `class="something"` to each element and just select that:

```
$('.something').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Wouldn't this display the section for all articles if any one is clicked? Or are the commas acting as 'ors' ? thanks for the answer

Comment: No, you're attaching the click handler to each selected element.  When that handler function is invoked, its `this` is set to the element that was actually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class for the click event, instead of ids .. you can then use the id or some other attribute to identify which article to expand.

```
$('.someClass').click(function() {
          thisId = $(this).attr('id');

            $('#whereTheSectionsAre').find('.active').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(400);
            $(thisId+'article').toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(400);

          return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check some examples here, mainly if the id's are dynamic:

http://jsbin.com/uzEkiQa/3/

The first approach is the one already suggested, but with dynamic id's:

```
$('div[id^="id_"]').text("Changed by regexep");
```

The second one if your matching is a bit more hardcore uses filter:

var reg = new RegExp(/id_\d+/);

```
  $('div[id^="id_"]')
  .filter(function(index, item) {
    return reg.test(item.id);
  })
  .text("Changed by filter and regexp");
```

After the selection you can apply the behaviours you want. Check the JSBin to play around.